# How can I attached pdf file which are already generated through react-pdf in email use nodemailer

Tags: reactjs, pdf-generation, nodemailer, react-pdf

I am a new developer and Now Iam work in react project and I have to attach pdf file which it is already generated in client through use react-pdf in email will be send through use nodemailer.
I am search through google but iam not find the right solution so may be can someone help me in that.

Here is the generate pdf ,style pdf in client side and nodemailer in server side

Here is the generated pdf in client:

```
`  
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js/dist/html2pdf.min";
import Pdf from "./Pdf";

function generatePDF(userProfile) {
  const printElement = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    Pdf({
      profilepicture: userProfile.profilepicture,
      firstname: userProfile.firstname,
      lastname: userProfile.lastname,
      designation: userProfile.designation,
      email: userProfile.email,
      phonenumber: userProfile.phonenumber,
      summary: userProfile.summary,
      experience:userProfile.experience,
      education:userProfile.education,
      projects:userProfile.projects,
      technologies:userProfile.technologies
    })
  );

  var opt = {
    margin:       [15, 0, 30, 0], //top, left, buttom, right,
    enableLinks: true,
    filename: "pdfreport",
    html2canvas: { useCORS: true },
    jsPDF: {},
  };

  html2pdf()
    .from(printElement)
    .set(opt)
    .toPdf()
    .get("pdf")
    .then(function (pdf) {
      pdf.setPage(1);
      
    })
    .save();
}
export default {
  generatePDF,
  };


and here is the nodemailer in the server side:

import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

const sendEmail = async (subject, message, send_to, sent_from, reply_to ) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: "465",
    secure: "true",
    auth: {
      
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    },
  
   });
   
  const options = {
    from: sent_from,
    to: send_to,
    replyTo: reply_to,
    subject: subject,
    html: message,
    attachment: [{
      filename: "pdfreport",
      
  

    }]
   

  
   
  };

  // Send Email
  transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(info);
    }
  });
};

export default sendEmail;
  `
```

Answer (score 0):

The [nodemailer documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) explains how to add attachments.  In your options object you currently have:

```
attachment: [{
  filename: "pdfreport",
  
}]
```

You need:

```
attachments: [{
  filename: "pdfreport",
  content: // string, buffer, stream, or file path
}]
```

You haven't made it clear how the PDF is being saved or sent to the server.  If it's being saved with html2pdf.js, that is happening on the client-side, and if you are using nodemailer, that is happening server-side. You need to make sure you understand how the pdf data is getting to the server, and then you will know what to put in the "content" property of the nodemailer options